# Dynamically add colspans and/or rowspans to a table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I like to dynamically add colspans and/or rowspans to a table cell, when it contains a specific content that is the same like the one in the neighbour cell. It's allowed to be done with jQuery.

Status:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>E</td>
    <td>E</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>W</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Y</td>
    <td>E</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

should look like

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">E</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Y</td>
    <td>W</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>E</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Fiddle example can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/rtcd9r4g/

First "seatmap" is current status, second one what it should look like.

Thx for any idea!!!

Comment: what is the criteria to add rowspan or colspan, because in the jsfiddle link shared `td` with class `seatAvailableExtraPay` has `rowspan="2" colspan="2"` at one place and only `rowspan="2"` at another.

Comment: If there are two cells with the same content (which also would mean that the cells will have the same class) side by side, the first cell will have a colspan and the second cell dissapears.
If there are two cells with the same content (or class) sitting above/underneath each other, the first cell will get a rowsapn and the second one dissapears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code. Attach it to the end of your JS.

```
var i = 0;
var $trs = $('#cabin1 tr');
$trs.each(function() {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td');
    var width = $tds.length;
    var num = 2;
    for(i = width - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        if($($tds[i]).html() == $($tds[i + 1]).html() && $($tds[i]).html() != ""){
            $($tds[i]).attr('colspan', num);
            num++;
            $($tds[i + 1]).remove();
        } else {
            num = 2;
        }
    }
    $tds = $(this).find('td');
    width = $tds.length;
    $($tds[0]).attr('seq', 0);
    for(i = 1; i < width; i++) {
        $($tds[i]).attr('seq', parseInt($($tds[i - 1]).attr('seq')) + $($tds[i - 1]).prop('colspan'));
    }
});

var height = $trs.length;
var j = 0;

for(i = height - 2; i >= 0; i--){
    $($trs[i]).find('td').each(function() {
        var seq = parseInt($(this).attr('seq'));
        var $tdUnder = $($trs[i + 1]).find('td[seq="' + seq + '"]');
        if($tdUnder.length && ($tdUnder.html() != "") && ($tdUnder.html() == $(this).html()) && ($tdUnder.prop('colspan') == $(this).prop('colspan'))) {
            $(this).prop('rowspan', $tdUnder.prop('rowspan') + 1);
            $tdUnder.remove();
        }
    });
}
```

You can see the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/Frederick888/rtcd9r4g/55/

Comment: I forgot to check colspan when merging TDs in different rows. Fixed now, please notice.

Comment: THIS - IS - AWESOME !!! Works like a charm! 
Just one question for understanding the whole code: for what do you use   var num = 2;

Comment: When merging TDs in the same row, the code will check if a TD is the same to the one right to it one by one from the last but one TD to the first. If they're the same, colspan of current TD will be set and the TD right to it will be deleted. So if the last but one TD and the last TD are the same, the colspan of last but one will be set to 2. This is why.

Comment: but there could be even 4 or 6 or more tds with the same content. Shouldn't it be colspan="6" in this case then ?

Comment: So there's a `num++` after colspan is set. If there're many continuous same TDs, the colspan will be set to 2, 3, 4, ... but not always 2. You can also have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Frederick888/rtcd9r4g/53/ . This one equals to the one in my answer and it may be easier to understand.

Comment: sorry there's a little bug. use this instead: http://jsfiddle.net/Frederick888/rtcd9r4g/54/ @SchweizerSchoggi

Comment: Perfect, Frederic, now I understand! Thank you so much for great work AND explanation of the code!

Comment: Frederic, are you still around? I am thinking about extended use of this seatmap thing. How do I have do adapt the code if there is more than ONE plane? I am also thinking about grouping tds with the same class instead with the same content. Is this an easy thing to change?

Comment: grouping tds with the same class is simple, just use `.attr('class')` instead of `.html()`. but what do you mean more than one plane? could you please give an jsfiddle example? @SchweizerSchoggi

Comment: ah you're right.... as easy as it could be! Thx!!
Regarding to have more than one plane: I have an accordion with let's say 4 or 6 seatmaps("planes"). But I see, I can use 
var $trs = $('.cabin tr');
instead of
var $trs = $('#cabin1 tr');
so that will work perfect for me!!

Comment: @FrederickZhang You've saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery, and adding an unique id to each cell:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td id="1-1">E</td>
    <td id="1-2">E</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="2-1">Y</td>
    <td id="2-2">W</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td id="3-1">Y</td>
    <td id="3-2">E</td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
$("#1-1").attr("colspan","2");
$("#1-2").remove();
$("#2-1").attr("rowspan","2");
$("#3-1").remove();
</script>
```

Comment: The content is dynamically generated, so I don't know what the content of each id will be. So before I can add colspan and rowspan the way you did I have to identify the content of each cell and compare it to its "neighbour cell"

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
//function to check adjucent tds
var colspanCount = 1;
var validateAdjucentTd = function(adjacentTd, classOfTd){
    var $adjacentTd= $(adjacentTd);
    //check if next row td of adjacent td has same class
    var indexOfadjacentTd = $adjacentTd.index();  
    var $nextRowTdOfadjacentTd = $adjacentTd.closest('tr').next('tr').find(':nth-child('+(indexOfadjacentTd + 1)+')');          
    //mark both tds for removal
    if(classOfTd == $nextRowTdOfadjacentTd.attr('class'))
    {
        $nextRowTdOfadjacentTd.addClass('tdToRemove');
        $adjacentTd.addClass('tdToRemove');
        colspanCount++;
        var nextTd = $adjacentTd.next('td');
        if(classOfTd == $(nextTd).attr('class'))
          validateAdjucentTd(nextTd, classOfTd);  
    }
}
//iterate all Tds
    $('table tr td').each(function(){
        //reset colspan count
        colspanCount = 1;
        //check if td is not empty and not marked for removal
        if(!$(this).is(':empty') && !$(this).hasClass('tdToRemove'))
       {
           var indexOfTd = $(this).index();
           var classOfTd = $(this).attr('class');
           //get TD from next row using index of current td
           var $nextRowTd = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr').find(':nth-child('+(indexOfTd + 1)+')');
           //get adjacent td
           var $adjacentTd = $(this).next('td');
          //if class matches for next row td then mark it for removal
          if(classOfTd == $nextRowTd.attr('class'))
          {
            $nextRowTd.addClass('tdToRemove');
            $(this).data('rowspan','2');
            $(this).addClass('spanToAdd');
          }

          //if class of adjacent td matches
          if(classOfTd == $adjacentTd.attr('class'))
          {
            validateAdjucentTd($adjacentTd, classOfTd);
            if(colspanCount > 1)
              {
                $(this).data('colspan',colspanCount);
                $(this).addClass('spanToAdd');
              }
          }   
        }      
    });

   //remove all td marked for removal
   $('.tdToRemove').remove();

   //modify colspan and rowspan of the tds identified
   $('table tr td.spanToAdd').each(function(){
      var rowSpan = parseInt($(this).data('rowspan')) || 1;
      var colSpan = parseInt($(this).data('colspan')) || 1;    
      $(this).attr('rowspan',rowSpan); 
      $(this).attr('colspan',colSpan); 
   });
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/rtcd9r4g/58/)**

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle more than 2 adjucent tds, there is no hardcoded value

Comment: Bhushan, this works perfect as well, thank you so much!! I accepted Frederics answer meanwhile 'cause he gave a correct solution first.